# Typescript: How to define a type for a callback that shouldn't return anything?

Tags: typescript, types

I mean it should return `undefined` or no return at all. Typical for safe callbacks.

Tryout 1:

```
declare const fn1: (cb: () => void) => void;
fn1(() => '123'); // no error
```

Oops. It didn't work out. `string` is applicable to `void`. Ok...

Tryout 2:

```
declare const fn2: (cb: () => unknown) => void;
fn2(() => '123'); // no error
```

Oops. The same. Ooookay.

Tryout 3:

```
declare const fn3: (cb: () => undefined) => void;
fn3(() => '123'); // error: Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'undefined'
```

Nice! Ok, go with it:

```
fn3(() => undefined); // okay
fn3(() => {}); // error: Type 'void' is not assignable to type 'undefined'
```

Hm. It's not what I'm looking for.

Okay, what's about this crazy idea? Tryout 4:

```
declare const fn4: (cb: () => void | undefined) => void;
fn4(() => undefined); // okay
fn4(() => { }); // okay
fn4(() => '123'); // error: Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'undefined'
```

Wow. It's what I wanted.

But it looks like a dirty hack. Why on the Earth `void` doesn't complain about `string`, but `void | undefined` does it? Is it a bug?

Can I rely on this behavior? Wouldn't it be fixed in some future versions of TS? Is there any better way to accomplish the same?

Comment: I'm intrigued, what the use case here? Why is it vital that the callback not return something (other than `undefined`)?

Comment: e.g.: in React: `onClick={props.openDialog}` where `openDialog: () => unknown | void`. It allows us to be sure that this callback (that doesn't know anything about event and that `return false -> preventDefault`) won't break any behavior. And it allows us to avoid wrapping it with something like `onClick={() => { props.openDialog(); }}`

Comment: I think the "right" thing here would be for something like [microsoft/TypeScript#36288](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/36288) to be implemented and then you'd just use `undefined`.  But of course it's not implemented (yet?) so this question remains

Comment: [This comment](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/35236#issuecomment-559213683) makes me apprehensive about saying "just keep using `void | undefined`" but that's not definitive.

Comment: @jcalz thanks. Yeah, it looks like an illegal tricky type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATED 2**

a callback that shouldn't have any args even optional and shouldn't return anything should be defined like that:

```js
type callback = (...a: void[]) => void | undefined;

const func = (a: callback) => { 
    a();
};

const test1 = func(() => { }); // works
const test2 = func((a?: string) => { }); // fails
const test2 = func(() => '5'); // fails
```

**UPDATED**

after discussion in comments was found out that the goal is to get a callback not with ignored return, but with guarantee that it won't return anything else and it can be passed to other functions that change behavior based on returned value.

In this case I would suggest to add a small helper function that really ignores any returned value.

```js
const shutUp = <T extends (...args: any) => void>(func: T): ((...args: Parameters<T>) => void) => (...args: any[]) => {
    func(...args);
};

const shutUpNoArgs = <T extends () => void>(func: T): ((...args: never) => void) => () => {
    func();
};

const test = shutUp((a: string) => 5);

const r1 = test('5'); // works, r1 is void.
const r2 = test(5); // doesn't work.

_.forEach(data, shutUp(callback));
```

**ORIGINAL**

You shouldn't be so strict and to worry too much about that.

`void` means we don't care about return, should we if we don't rely on it?

It's the same as to say that we don't accept a function because it doesn't require our `a` argument despite it can handle the case.

```js
declare const fn1: (cb: (a: string) => void) => void;

fn1(() => {
}); // no error even we don't have `a` in our callback.
```

Docs: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#void

> `void` is a little like the opposite of `any`: the absence of having any type at all.

Therefore, its behavior won't be changed you can use it in a union with `undefined`.

Comment: Sorry. It looks like you misunderstood the question. I really RELY ON it. So I really care about return. That's why I need to be assured that the callback doesn't return anything (except undefined). So, my questions isn't about void :) My question is about how to guarantee using TS that the function doesn't use return (or always returns undefined).

Reasons why I am interesting in such a guarantee isn't described in this question. But they definitely are. I prefer FP to OOP and use functions a lot.

Comment: If you rely on it then you need to mark it as `undefined`. I can hardly imagine a case where you would need it. Might you give me an example? Just for experience :)

Comment: as I understood the question was why `void` accepts `string` and I gave an answer on it. `void` doesn't care about return, it doesn't limit types and no, it won't be fixed because it's how `void` works.

Comment: I understand why `void` accepts `string`. The sub-question is about why at the same time  `void | undefined` doesn't accept `string`. In my mind if you use `|` operator it always means that the resulting type will be more wide. But in this case it's the opposite.

Comment: Example of when I need it: I have a React application. I have a DOM-node. This DOM-node accepts lots of events. Let it be "onClick". My component accept some handler as a react-prop. I want to set it to the `onClick` to this DOM-node as a handler. But I don't want to allow this handler to do anything to the event.

Comment: I don't what this callback being able to run `event.preventDefault`, `event.stopPropagation` and so on. I don't want to provide more than it really needs. For this case I need a tool to limit the handler accesses. If the handler will return `false` it'll automatically "prevent default" the event.

Comment: It's not only about DOM-Events. It's about providing callbacks to some generic methods without wrapping them by another one function that skips the return.

Comment: E.g. `_.transform` and `_.forEach` breaks iteration cicle when provided callback returns `false`. So I cannot run them with any callback. I have to be sure that the callback doesn't return false. And so on. 

P.S. SO forced me to split my reply by 4 sub-comments, lol

Comment: Aha, thanks for the info, makes sense, what about to have s simple wrapper that ignores the returned value? then you can accept real `void` and in the same time ensure that its result is ignored further. something like `_.forEach(shutUp(callback))` where `shatUp = func => (...args) => {func(...args)}`;.

Comment: Yeah. We made the wrapper. And made even 2 versions of it. The 2nd version ignores also arguments. Because when you write `() => void` to avoid using `event`, it anyway allows us to set something like `(arg?: string) => void` and, as you can notice, `string` isn't `Event` :) So it seems TS cannot help us with it.

Also we use WeakMap to preserve these `shutUp` wrappers (because of immutability and shallow comparisons).

Comment: sounds like a military base :) your truth, with args its easier, you can use `never` like that ` (...args: never[]): void | undefined`, but in case of return `never` means a function will throw an error, I've updated my answer, perhaps it fits now. Anyway was an interesting topic. Thanks!

Comment: It's interesting idea about `never`. But I've tried and it seems it doesn't work. It accepts any arguments without complaining.

Comment: missed couple of changes, now it should work as desired: https://take.ms/W3ceN

Comment: yeah, you are right, the signature doesn't do its work :) crazy TS.

Comment: It looks like we're talking about a bit different things. I meant this: [Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#code/C4TwDgpgBAKgwgQwDZIEYIMYGsoF4oAUAdCQgE4DmAzgFxQB2EAbhGQNoC6AlHgHxRMA9gEsAJgG4AUKIgYk5aBkH0qwKAHcyCMJDJ0CAM3p14yNJiw9c-IWKmbtuggSv8A3lAC+XcVAD0fgyCUKxkgmQANFAIVFAyVMJkEKKSDjqszgh0qmTC9BSuUB7evgFBIWRhkVCoAK5qVAAWgrVIojUQkkA). Your function cannot be executed with arguments. My function must not accept a callback with arguments as an argument.

But... when I change `never` to `unknown` it works as desired.

Comment: magically `void` works here: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/C4TwDgpgBAxghgGwQIzjA1lAvFAFAOkLgC4oA3AewEsATAbQF0BKbAPnOpqgB8oBXAHY0IAMyoCINANwAoGTAoCAzsCgjBMbHhKxEKNOhZZ2AbygyolqHFxNZAX1nzFKqMAgqAjFvUCYuWzYoM3s7Z2VVdxUAJh8NALgAflIVACdxAHMjUyhQ2QUItw9gWJxff0DjKAByAFZqsKA

Comment: Yeah! Finally we have found __the TS way__ to accomplish desired behavior. Unfortunately it looks like we use some __black magic__ here. So I think it'd be much more reliable and reasonable to just use some runtime wrapper. I marked your answer as correct. Thanks!